# Handle the httpmodule in iis

Tags: c#, asp.net

If you see the yahoo site, when you enter www.yahoo.com, the yahoo server gets your IP, and redirects you to the specific domain (yahoo.ca,yahoo.us,....)

Now, I want do this,Not for  special site, I want to get any request send to iis
 (www.1.com,www.2.com,www.3.com) and with the algorithm, redirect user to the new site for example:

```
 Request: www.1.com GO To -> www.yahoo.com
 Request: www.2.com GO To -> www.google.com
 ....
```

I want handle IIS, no each webconfig's site.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

implementing the IHttpModule you can do this, I've done the similar (not exactly) by following this guide:

http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/http-module-to-redirect-requests-from-root-domain-to-www-subdomain/

and using this [page](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/06/finding-country-from-visitors-ip-in.html) you can find the source country of the request

another solution in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270091/how-to-determine-if-an-ip-address-belongs-to-a-country)

Comment: Thanks Jadarnel,this is my first question.

Comment: But this link is usefull when You want to impelement for one website,but i want to do it for all the websites ,are on the severe.
I need to handle http module in iis level ,no application.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that, but using the above guide, you can add the module as a standalone dll to every web application where ever they are, btw you need to publish your site on those servers, don't you?

Comment: Yes.i Need to handle hhtpmodule on IIS ,not each webSites.

Comment: +1 for the interesting link for the stardeveloper setup. The OP could adopt this route for free :-) with the downsides being the need to install, invoke and manage the module in each app, as well as carefully configure their domain setup.

Comment: Thanks dash, yes it's a quite interesting article. glad you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Afshin's answer versus discovering a user's geographical location [also look at this.](http://www.countryipblocks.net/bogons/)

Unfortunately, a HTTP Module only works at the web site level; to do what you need you have to look at [ISAPI_Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx for more information.

We ended up buying a product linked from that page; [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)

Comment: honesty, is installing an ISAPI easier than httpmodule? knowing the fact that you need to install the web application though...

Comment: It's easier to manage with the ISAPI filter as it's server wide. However, you could potentially do it with individual ASP.Net apps but you'd be increasing the load on each additional app, would have to manage the module in each app, and would also have to do it in each subdomain you created.

Comment: I notice that ISAPI Rewrite offer a LITE version. It may be worth looking at the documentation for that.