# How to get current country without using "LocationManager" or "NSLocale"?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, location

I want to get my current country ; but I don't want to use "LocationManager" or "NSLocale" 
 I just need the name of the country.
any idea please?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is there a reason you dont want to use NSLocale or LocationManager?

Comment: without the use of locationmanager or nslocale you won't get the lat long of your current position so you can't find country as well must have to use one of those

Comment: LocationManager will ask user for permission to get his location, i think most of users will not allow this
NSLocale: I'm in jordan and my iPhone language is US so NSLocale return United States

Comment: i was thinking to get location from wifi info
but i don't know how to do this..

Answer (score 5):

You should try to get Cellular information

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

// Setup the Network Info and create a CTCarrier object
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];

// Get carrier name
NSString *carrierName = [carrier carrierName];
if (carrierName != nil)
  NSLog(@"Carrier: %@", carrierName);

// Get mobile country code
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
if (mcc != nil)
  NSLog(@"Mobile Country Code (MCC): %@", mcc);

// Get mobile network code
NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
if (mnc != nil)
  NSLog(@"Mobile Network Code (MNC): %@", mnc);
```

**OR**

You should try to get Country from the device IP Address

[Identifying country by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802046/identifying-country-by-ip-address)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the problem with cellular info
that i cant use it for iPod or iPad, so i will check for public IP address
Thanks Alot

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by calling this url

http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp

also you can call for testing http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=3.255.255.255

Answer (score 0):

Try this please it will work 100 with latest PHP versions

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$Details=unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip));
```

If you want to check the complete array try this below one

```
echo var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip)));
```