# Detect Country then show message?

Tags: javascript, location, alert

I have a US and UK website. If the user is from the UK, and is on the US website, then show a message on a page to redirect to the correct site. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the IP in a geo database, such as GeoLite (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite), to figure out where the user is located.

GeoLite databases can be downloaded to your app. Then simply create a small server endpoint to make IP lookups in the database.

Using JavaScript you can then:

1. Grab the IP of the current user
2. Look up the location in the GeoLite database through the server endpoint
3. If in UK on US site (or vice versa) -> display message and optionally redirect the user to the correct website

Of course you could also do this server-side, and automatically redirect the user if that's your preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to get the IP and use a geo-location lookup as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802046/identifying-country-by-ip-address) thread? Once you know the IP you can get the country and redirect as required.