# Redirect Based On IP Address

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, ip

Lets say I have domain http://domain.ru and a English visitor visits, it shows me English website based on IP sent him to /eng/ but If a Russian user went on send that person to /ru/

Instead of a User selecting an address I would like to filter only Russia and other countries, meaning that even if your in France you shall visit /eng/ but IF you are in Russia you visit /ru/

Any tips to do this? Or Recommendations?

Comment: when any user,  hit the site you have their IP, and can determine from IP from which country visitor belongs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website that recognizes user's location/IP & changes lang. based on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039016/website-that-recognizes-users-location-ip-changes-lang-based-on-that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get IP address of incoming request using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270091/how-to-determine-if-an-ip-address-belongs-to-a-country) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802046/identifying-country-by-ip-address) questions on how to map your IP address to a country.

There are several free SQL database with IP mapping [here](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php). They also have [API](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php).

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are not assigned in blocks to countries, so there is no easy way to do this. The best solution i've used is a third party database of IPs from a company called MaxMind - they have an open source version of the database at http://www.maxmind.com/en/opensource and there are many tutorials online for integrating this with a PHP application.

Answer (score 0):

You can user thrid party integration. There is a third party service, that [detects country based upon user IP](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/redirecting-users-to-sub-sites-based-on-their-country-ip#)